# How to view the source or markup of Grails' templates when using Chrome?

Tags: grails

When a GSP is rendered and then the user interacts with it causing a template to be rendered onto some part of the GSP, how can I view the source code or markup of the template? In Chrome dev tools I am only able to see the markup of the main GSP but not the template.

Comment: I have seen the code in firefox if I right click the page and go to inspect element, which will give the source in a list there.

Comment: @Ted Delezene Interesting, I wonder how to get to it with Chrome?

Comment: Do you want to see the source of the template itself or the markup generated by the the template? The former is not possible, because only the latter is sent to the browser

Comment: @Donal I wish to see the latter.

Comment: Same way it looks like it's nearly identical.  navigate through the different `div`'s find the one that contains your template and expand it.

Comment: @Ted Delezene That's what makes sense to do so I tried it and found that it still looks like the parent GSP did before the template loaded. I don't see the newer template code even though the template has been rendered and is visible.